# How to prevent scrolling to top after async update in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

After async request I add a new element on top like this:

```
Array.prototype.unshift.apply(scope.conversation, conversation.data.message);
```

The problem is that after the element is added, the scroll position automatically moves to top. How can I maintain the same scroll position after my update?

I am using Angular 1.

Comment: You need to do it manually. I mean, save the before scroll position and the height, and after the DOM changed, calculate which scroll position should be. Please add a snippet so it will be much easier us for help.

Comment: Can I calculate position from bottom to current scroll position and after ajax request to submit tahat same position? or ti disable somehow that beheviour?

Comment: `from bottom` = scrollTop - height.

Comment: How then I can submit that scroll position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of how to calculate the `scrollTop` after adding objects to the array.

The logic is:

1. Save the `scrollTop` and the `scrollHeight` before adding.
2. Add the items.
3. Set the `scrollTop` by calc the delta of the height (by adding new items) and scroll to this height + the old `scrollTop`.

Keep it in your mind that there is a "jump" between the adding items and the new `scrollTop`. I don't think that you can over it unless you do some fadeOut/fadeIn or scrollTo with transition to cover this "jump".

Let me know if something not clear.

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.index = 0;
  $scope.convert = function(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = $scope.index++;
    }
    
    return arr;
  };
  
  $scope.items = $scope.convert(new Array(50));

  $scope.add = function() {
    var $container = $('.container');
    var container = $container[0];
    
    var scrollTop = $container.scrollTop();
    var oldHeight = container.scrollHeight;
    Array.prototype.unshift.apply($scope.items, $scope.convert(new Array(50)));
    $timeout(function(){
      var diff = container.scrollHeight - oldHeight;
      $container.scrollTop(diff + scrollTop);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" class="scroll">
      Item {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add items</button>
</div>
```